# Count groups of negatives int's in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a array of ints 
`var arr = [-1,-2,-1,0,-1,-2,-1,-2,-1,0,1,0]`

I want to get the number of groups of negatives, in this case is 2

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: when you say "groups of negatives" what do you mean?  `-1,-2,-1` and `-1,-2,-1,-2,-1` ?

Comment: Pseudocode: You need to squash your array down to unique values; Then, search the squashed values for negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Number of negative groups are number of negative elements which are proceeded by non-negative number or they are last element of array.

- Use the `reduce()` method on array and set accumulator to `0`
- Check if the current number is negative and number next to it is non-negative or doesn't exist then increment the counter otherwise don't.

```js
const groups = arr => arr.reduce((ac,a,i) => ac + (a < 0 && (!arr[i+1] || arr[i+1] >=0) ? 1 : 0 ),0)

console.log(groups([-1,-2,-1,0,-1,-2,-1,-2,-1,0,1,0]))
console.log(groups([-1,-2,-1,-2,-1,0,1,0,-1,-1]))
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer Nice catch. I have fixed it.

Comment: Another fix you might have applied for that error: `arr => [...arr, 0].reduce(...)`

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for suggestion. But I think this is fine.

Comment: That is absolutely fine.  I had written an answer equivalent to yours, with the same possible fencepost error and was about to post it when I saw the comment on yours, I fixed mine in a different way.  Just thought I'd share a different technique.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the check of the predecessor of the item, if not smaller than zero (to cover `undefined`) and if the value is smaller than zero, to the sum.

```js
const
    groups = array => array.reduce(
        (s, b, i, { [i - 1]: a }) => s + (!(a < 0) && b < 0),
        0
    );

console.log(groups([-1, -2, -1, 0, -1, -2, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 0]));
console.log(groups([-1, -2, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1]));
```